# latex not producing a particular citation in beamer

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am trying to cite an article. The `.bib` file is:

```
@Article{jensenandco2017,
  Title                    = {Fast and Accurate Prediction of the Regioselectivity of Electrophilic Aromatic Substitution Reactions},
  Author                   = {Kromann Jimmy, Jensen Jan, Kruszyk Monika, Jessing Mikkel, Jorgensen Morten},
  Journal                  = {ChemRxiv},
  Year                     = {2017},
  Number                   = {0},
  Pages                    = {0},

  Publisher                = {Royal Society of Chemistry}
}
```

texmaker terminal returns:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'jensenandco2017' on page 5 undefined on input line 130
```

**EDIT**

Biber returns:

```
  Found BibTeX data source 'poweP.bib' WARN - Name "Kromann Jimmy, 
Jensen Jan, Kruszyk Monika, Jessing Mikkel, Jorgensen Morten" has too
 many commas: skipping name WARN - Range field 'pages' in entry 
'jensenandco2017' is malformed, falling back to literal INFO - 
Overriding locale 'es-ES' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable
 = non-ignorable' INFO - Overriding locale 'es-ES' defaults 
'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized' INFO - 
Sorting list 'nty/global/' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and 
locale 'es-ES' INFO - Writing 'poweP.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8' INFO -
 Output to poweP.bbl INFO - WARNINGS: 2
```

Comment: fonts are unrelated to your question (as is the part of the log you showed) . You have given very few clues, but you tagged the question biber so are you using biblatex/biber rather than bibtex? have you a \cite{jensenandco2017} have you run biber (or bibtex) have you run latex enough times to resolve all references?

Comment: hmm..did you look at the update post? I suppose fonts were related because of the warning. I am using biblatex/biber. Yes, all citations work and it is exactly cited as you wrote..@DavidCarlisle

Comment: Also, I have removed all related files and compiled using `quickbuild` which is: pdf-->biblatex-->pdfx2 @DavidCarlisle

Comment: if you cite that then run biber it should either generate the bibliography or give an error in its log, then when you next run latex the reference should work or give an error in the log but it's impossible to debug code you have not shown with with errors that you have not shown!

Comment: updated @DavidCarlisle

Comment: I understand about the commas, I will try modifying that. The cite was constructed by me, because there isn't any bibtex code to use in jabref for that paper @DavidCarlisle

Comment: so there you are biber _tells you_ it is ignoring that entry,  `Range field 'pages' in entry 
'jensenandco2017' is malformed, falling back to literal`

Comment: yes but how is malformed `'pages'`? I don't know how to correct that part @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @Schopenhauer I assume the article doesn't have no pages so just delete that line (and the blank after it I would guess)

Comment: I removed some commas (and names) and it works..Yes it has no pages (joke). Thanks, answer the question if you want..@DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If biber skips an entry it always leaves a message in the log file saying why. In this case

```
Range field 'pages' in entry 'jensenandco2017' is malformed,
```

It is objecting to

```
  Pages                    = {0},
```

as an article with no pages doesn't make sense.

The error

```
 has too many commas:
```

is because multiple authors should be separated with `and` not by commas,

Note also that

```
 Number                   = {0},
```

Is probably also wrong. It is generally better to remove (or correct) bad fields rather than pad them with spurious data such as 0 which then produce poor reference data in your document (if they don't get filtered by biber)

Comment: Are you shure that commas don't need to be modified?Also the las paragraph in your answer might be "It is generally better.." or maybe I misunderstood it. Thanks for the help..

Comment: It is the entry shown, as far as I understand (not very far). Look at the author names..

Comment: @Schopenhauer I addressed the comma error now